# Substring text with javascript including html tags

Tags: javascript

i wanted to substring a string something like follow. And i have start position and length of the string . 
i have checked this ques [Substring text with HTML tags in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003271/substring-text-with-html-tags-in-javascript). But in this substring is performing from 0 but i have a random start position. Any idea about how it will done

```
var str = 'Lorem ipsum <p>dolor <strong>sit</strong> amet</p>, consectetur adipiscing elit.'
```

Comment: @Alex i wanted the substring with its parent html tags.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/danmana/5mNNU/ check this fiddle in this all is done . But its working by assuming start position 0 . But in my case i have a random start position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2ULbK/27/)**

```
function html_substr( str, start ,count ) {

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = str;

    walk( div, track );

    function track( el ) {
        if( count > 0 ) {
            var len = el.data.length;
            if(start<=len){
                el.data = el.substringData(start,len);
                start=0;
            } else{
                start-=len;
                el.data = '';
            }
            len = el.data.length;
            count -= len;
            if( count <= 0 ) {
                el.data = el.substringData( 0, el.data.length + count );
            }

        } else {
            el.data = '';
        }
    }

    function walk( el, fn ) {
        var node = el.firstChild;
        do {
            if( node.nodeType === 3 ) {
                fn(node);
            } else if( node.nodeType === 1 && node.childNodes && node.childNodes[0] ) {
                walk( node, fn );
            }
        } while( node = node.nextSibling );
    }
    return div.innerHTML;
}
```

Call it as

```
html_substr( str,13, 2 );
```

Comment: I have tested this quite thoroughly and it works every time. With nested tags and simple tags, as well as unclosed tags.  

To help understand the answer rahul has supplied here I will show the output of the three examples in the DEMO alongside the basic substr output

1) 
substr  : p> ;
html_substr : <p>ol<strong></strong></p>
----------
2) 
substr : orem ipsum <p>dolor ; 
html_substr : orem ipsum <p>dolor <strong>sit</strong></p>
-------------
3)
substr : rem ipsum <p>dolor <strong>sit  ; 
html_substr :  rem ipsum <p>dolor <strong>sit</strong> amet</p>, cons

Answer (score 0):

Here is a native DOM API approach to do this sort of thing. The browser already has powerful built in HTML parsing abilities. No need to re-invent the wheel

```
var el = document.createElement("div");
el.innerHTML = 'Lorem ipsum <p>dolor <strong>sit</strong> amet</p>, consectetur adipiscing elit.';
el.getElementsByTagName("p").textContent;
```

#### [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/adZXQ/)

The result is just a non-html string which you can easily manipulate with `.substring`

### So, how did this work?

We dumped our HTML into an HTML element.

Then we used the DOM API to say the following:

"Inside the HTML we just gave you, find all `p` tags, take the first (that's the [0]), and give us its textContent".