# javascript html substring in asp.net repeater

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, substring, repeater

Here is my code for repeater,

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="NewDataSource">
        <ItemTemplate>
               <%# Eval("Title") %><br />
               <%# Eval("PostDate","{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}")%><br/>
               <%# Eval("Body") %><br />
            <hr />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

In my data , `Body` is html string and I want to `substring` this not including html tags !

Example

If Body string is likes
`<span style="color: #996600">Detail </span>of my Body <span style="color: #669933">Text
</span>`

I want to show likes ,

`<span style="color: #996600">Detail </span>of my <span style="color: #669933">
</span>... ReadMore(to navigate detail Page)`

I found javascript function to do it in [Substring text with html tags in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6003271/1427849)

But I don't know how to use with my code ! Kindly , help me , Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this...

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="NewDataSource">
    <ItemTemplate>
           <%# Eval("Title") %><br />
           <%# Eval("PostDate","{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}")%><br/>
           <%# Regex.Replace(Eval("Body").toString(), "<.*?>", "").Substring(0, 10) & " ..." %> 
           <a href="">Read More</a><br />
        <hr />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Thanks Luke , but your code will `substring` all including html tags .I found the solution at the link refer in my question , but I just don't know how to use with my code !

Comment: you found a code in JS but you write currently in asp net C# or VB. Please see my update, where you can simply remove all html tags.

Comment: But I don't want to remove html tag :)

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/danmana/5mNNU/ , that's what I want to do . But I don't know how to implement this javascript in my code :)

Answer (score 0):

Why substring?

You can use css to control the words, and set the title to the full text at the same time.

```
.ellipsis-body{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Hopes to help you.

Comment: You need to set a width firstly.